# Integer enum values is valid but not string enum value

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I was learning Enums in typescript and came across this issue.
Let me know if anyone can help me understand it.

```js
enum Type {
  UPPER = 1,
  LOWER,
  CAMEL = "camelcase",
}
let myType: Type;
myType = 1; --- this is valid
myType = "camelcase" --- this is not
```

Do you help me understand why this does not work?

I tried checking various resources and documentation but somehow I did not find the proper explanation to it. I even talked to AI assitent but it also did not helped.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. Can you explain please?